# Teradata fast load file (csv, excel) into table with system date load date column

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

My question is can Teradata have a column in a table where when your loading a file(excel, csv) it will add the date you loaded that file into that table. I have researched this and supposedly it can be done but it does not work. I have done this in MySQL but not finding a way to do it in Teradata. Any help is appreciated.

table i created:

```
create multiset table ThisTable, fallback, 
 no before journal,
 no after journal,
 checksum = default,
default mergeblockratio,
map = TD_MAP1
 ( column1 int,
   column2 varchar(50) character set latin not casespecific,
   load_date date not null FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD' DATE
   --TD_TIMEBUCKET BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED SYSTEM TIMECOLUMN,
   --example I found in Teradata documents but errors out saying generated not match defined type.
    --TD_TIMECODE TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL GENERATED TIMECOLUMN
    --same error as above.
 )
PRIMARY INDEX ( column1, column2 );
```

Comment: The TD_TIMEBUCKET syntax is for Time Series Tables in TD16.20, but you probably want a simple `col DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE` or `col TIMESTAMP(0) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)`

Comment: Thank you for the help. Table gets created with using the Date with default current_date